# Sort values in a Pandas data frame by a temporary variable

Tags: python, pandas

In R, I can use `dplyr::arrange` to sort a data frame by a temporary variable. For example, using the NYC `flights` dataset in the `nycflights13` package, I can sort by velocity by computing this value from the `distance` and `air_time` columns:

```
library(nycflights13)
arrange(flights, distance / air_time)
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Pandas (without explicitly creating a new column, sorting by that column, and then removing this column again)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is possible by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), first can use [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) for sorting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print (df.A / df.D)
0    1.000000
1    0.666667
2    0.600000
dtype: float64

print ((df.A / df.D).sort_values())
2    0.600000
1    0.666667
0    1.000000
dtype: float64

print (df.reindex((df.A / df.D).sort_values().index))
   A  B  C  D  E  F
2  3  6  9  5  6  3
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
```

Comment: Nice, this works! Here's the syntax for sorting the `flights` data frame by velocity: `flights.reindex((flights.distance / flights.air_time).sort_values(ascending=False).index)`

Comment: Thank you. I have no your sample data (I am not `R` user, so I create sample data)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael - I've put the data on GitHub in case you want to run this specific example: https://github.com/cbrnr/py4ds/blob/master/flights.csv